# Angular binding different elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have got simple question: how to create binding between button and textarea? I see that like:

html

```
<textarea [value]="test"> <button (click)="onclick($event)>
```

ts

```
onclick(event: Event) {
  this.test = ($event.HowToChooseTarget as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

As you can see, the problem is to choose target element there. How to do this?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. With help of template ref variable

   ```
   <textarea #test [value]="test"> <button (click)="onclick(test.value)>
   ```
2. Use ngModel and directly access the value in your component file with "this.test"

   <textarea [(ngModel)]="test"> <button (click)="onclick($event)>

Comment: First way is useful for me, thank you. But how does ng understand, that test.value into  onclick(test.value) is connected with ref variable test, and not with component property "test"?